# How to dynamically set the event handler type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventhandler

I would like to dynamically set the event handler.

Example:

```
$('.test').on( 'click', function() {
  // My Code
});
```

Expecting (pseudo) code:

```
// .on or just on
var eventHandler = ".on"; 
$('.test')eventHandler( 'click', function() {
  // My Code
});
```

eventHandler could be "live", "click", "delegate", etc..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way to do it:

```js
var eventHandler = "on"; 

$('.test')[eventHandler]( 'click', function() {
  alert('Hello!')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='test'>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you very much Nosyara. 
I tried that approach at one point but it didn't work because I had the dot in the variable value (var eventHandler = ".on"; ).

Thanks again Nosyara.